# Running GwtDriver example app

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to run [gwt-driver example project](https://github.com/niloc132/gwt-driver-sample) however running the example app does not work:

```
$mvn jetty:run
```

However, `no plugin found for prefix 'jetty'` is thrown. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I might have a local config that makes it easier to run that - I'll modify the project pom so that this error doesn't happen, then answer with what was changed and why it needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Maven plugin is actually just an artifact, so needs to be fully qualified - groupId, artifactId, and version. This means that a goal like `jetty:run` actually is something like `org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run`.

The 'prefix' mentioned in the error is a way to refer to the plugin without all of that extra detail. The plugin declares a short name that can be used to describe it, so as long as you list the plugin in your pom, maven can look through each plugin and find the one with the matching prefix, and figure out the group and version from there. The version turns out to not be essential (though it is a good idea to list it), as maven will just look for the latest version of that plugin.

In the case of gwt-driver-sample, I just [committed](https://github.com/niloc132/gwt-driver-sample/commit/dc7efac3b9366fd409bd2fd3a14f99fc75a7fc80) a change to the pom.xml file that adds this in the `<build><plugins>` section:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
```

This is enough to tell maven how to find the right plugin when you call `mvn jetty:run` from the command line.